# I can't do a submit with jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

This is my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

    <script>
        function DoSubmit() {
            if ($("#noAggLabel")) {
                $("#noAggLabel").innerHTML = "";
            }
            if (this.value) {
                $("#orderForm").submit();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

<form action="/Orders/GetXML" id="orderForm" method="post">            <p>
                <select id="OrdersSelect" name="productionOrderId" onchange="DoSubmit();"><option value="">Orders</option>
<option value="1">Order 1</option>
<option value="2">Order 2</option>
<option value="3">Order 3</option>
</select>
            </p>
</form>    </div>
    <div id="codesTable">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm developing a ASP.NET MVC 5 app with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

This is the View that generates that HTML:

```
@model Models.ProductionOrderViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script>
        function DoSubmit() {
            if ($("#noAggLabel")) {
                $("#noAggLabel").innerHTML = "";
            }
            if (this.value) {
                $("#orderForm").submit();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("GetXML", "Orders", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "orderForm" }))
        {
            <p>
                @Html.DropDownList("productionOrderId",
                                    new SelectList(Model.ProductionOrders, "Id", "OrderNumber"),
                                    "Orders",
                                    new { id = "OrdersSelect", onchange = "DoSubmit();" })
            </p>
        }
    </div>
    @if (!Model.PagingInfo.HasAggregations)
    {
        <div id="noAggDiv">
            @Html.Label("No tiene agregaciones", new { @id = "noAggLabel" })
        </div> 
    }
    <div id="codesTable">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why I can't do a submit? I change selected value and nothing happens.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? The OP has provided more than enough code and a description of the problem. What more do you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the `DoSubmit` function isn't called with the element as the context. In the function `this` will refer to the `window` object.

You can set the context when you call the function:

```
onchange="DoSubmit.call(this);"
```

If you bind the event using jQuery instead of the `onchange` attribute, the context will be right:

```
$(function(){
  $('#OrdersSelect').change(DoSubmit);
});
```

---

Side notes: There is no `innerHTML` method in jQuery, you would use the `text` or `html` method to set the content. You don't have to check if there is any element first, if there is no element, then the jQuery object will be empty, so calling `text` on it just does nothing.

You should check the content of the value. If you just use it in an `if` statement it will be converted to a boolean, so an empty string is still evaluated as `true`.

```
function DoSubmit() {
    $("#noAggLabel").text("");
    if (this.value != "") {
        $("#orderForm").submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly! And also, I have fixed the problem with `"#noAggLabel"`.

Comment: @VansFannel: Also note what I added about the `if(this.value)` issue.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `onchange` attribute, and bind through jQuery

```
<script>
    function DoSubmit() {
        if ($("#noAggLabel").length) {
            $("#noAggLabel").html();
        }
        if (this.value) {
            $("#orderForm").submit();
        }
    }
    $(function(){
        $('#OrdersSelect').on('change', DoSubmit);
    });
</script>
```

Also add `.length` to the `$("#noAggLabel")` test because it always returns a jQuery object (*and it always evaluates to true when used in a boolean test*).